# Signing mac installer (pkgmaker)

Tags: macos, code-signing, packagemaker

My installer is created using PackageMaker. After that I codesigned the installer using the following command.

## productsign --sign 'Blah, Inc.' Install.mpkg/ CS/Install.mpkg

This seem to work pretty well and I could see that it is signed using the following command.

## pkgutil --check-signature Install.mpkg

Since the certificate is installed on my system in keychain, the installer seem to show a little lock on top right corner. Clicking this opens up the certificate.

If the installer is placed in a system without the certificate installed the lock is no longer seen. However I could still run the command to check for certificate.

1) Is there a graphical way to check for code signing before installing? (I do not want to run command line)

2) I removed a folder from the mpkg file using finder to see if the installer will complain of tampering. But that does not happen. Is there a way the installer can stop install if it is tampered?

3) I also code signed all the binaries in my package (mostly daemons) using xcode's option to use certificate. Again I am able to see the binary as signed, however I do get a message 
kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=224[MyDaemon] clearing CS_VALID.

Googling, I found http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/photoshop_13_0_4_x64_how_can_i_get_rid_of_the_could_not_complete_your_request_because_of_a . However I am still not very clear what they are getting at. Could someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sign only `flat packages`. Your package has extension .mpkg which I believe is the older bundle format. Make sure you are using flat packages if you want to sign them.

Comment: I am using packages. I tried flattening some time ago, and I thought it didn't allow plug-ins, I'll have to try again.

Answer (score 3):

You ***can*** sign .`mpkg` packages but you must sign it with the `Developer ID Application` cert and *not* the `Developer ID Installer` cert.

When you sign the `.mpkg` you get a number a warnings that the inner packages must be signed but the signing seems to be valid with or without the inner `.pkg` signed.

I have tested that modifying an internal .pkg causes the .mpkg to fail the Gatekeeper check
[image: Broken Installer]

So for the each internal .pkg files you should:

```
sudo productsign --sign "<Developer ID Installer: Cert>" "<source.mpkg>/Contents/Packages/<source.pkg>" "<destination.mpkg>/Contents/Packages/<source.pkg>"
```

for then for the .mpkg do:

```
sudo productsign --sign "<Developer ID Application: Cert>" "<Source .mpkg>" "<Destination .mpkg>"
```

Comment: Makes sense. Anyways I moved to flat packages. I think that is better.

Comment: I couldn't flatten it because I had plug-ins; but yes it's easier to flatten if you can.

Comment: Thats odd, I have a plugin too. I assume the plugin used to insert extra steps in the install process. I could flatten it even with plugin. Try using Packages (http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) instead of PackageMaker. This allows you to flatten it even with plugin.

Comment: @hoss i have struck this issue. can you help to resolve my issue