# can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, daemon, code-signing

I have developed an application and daemon in Mac OSX and i have signed with developer id both Application and Daemon source in xcode. In daemon, i have signed each framework and packaged, and i have pkg to all using package installer. Now my app is .mpkg.

i have signed this mpkg also. and each package is also signed. i have check in terminal. it shows my developer id and i have checked everything is signed in my mpkg.

I have release out of mac store.

i have install without signed, then the mac says,

> Myapp.mpkg Can't be opened because it is unidentified developer

now change settings to "System Preferences... > Security & Privacy --> Mac App Store and identified developers" then  i try to install my signed mpkg, the mac says now,

> "MyApp.mpkg can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed"

see the both msg now, its shows now identity developer".

i have googled. it says go to enable Open anyway in sequrity &privacy under Mac appstore and identiied deverloper" check below image

[image]

What is the use of this. Now my question is

```
1 .Is i'm signed mpkg properly.

2. If i signed properly and i'm valid developer, then why it ask permission in security page.

3. Is this confirm "Open Anyway" this msg whenever i try to install?

4. If i did this, next time this will not ask, so how can i disallow.
```

can you anybody clarify my doubt. I need to send it to client for those things about this. 
Thanks for Advance.

Comment: @Droppy i dnt know, i am signed properly?

Comment: It might be you've not used the correct certificate.  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049985/signing-mac-installer-pkgmaker).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Open 'System Preferences'
2. Go to 'Security & Privacy' and tap on 'General' tab
3. Click on 'Lock' icon which you can find on bottom left screen and type your administrator password.
4. The last step is to choose 'Anywhere' under 'Allow apps downloaded from:' and then again click on 'Lock' icon.
5. Now you can run any apps.

Comment: The "Anywhere" option is now gone in Sierra. When opening fails, there will be an "Open Anyway" button in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General` and then when you click that you get ANOTHER warning and you have to ultimately click the `Open` button and it will work. I keep running into this for Android Studio Canary builds and it is annoying. Apple is borrowing a page out of Window's playbook.

Comment: the `Open` button is not even present on my Mojave when I try to run Gimp on

Answer (score 11):

Here's an alternative for people googling the error message on software they haven't developed themselves.

For raw binaries, disk images, archives, etc.:

```
xattr -c path/to/file
```

For applications (or extracted folders):

```
find path/to/name.app -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -c
```

Comment: -c clears all extended attributes. That works, but actually it's enough to delete the com.apple.quarantine attribute with `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine myfile`.

Comment: There was only one attribute on the binary I downloaded, so it was all the same. You can perform `xattr [-l] /path/to/file` to list the attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to run the following in your command line.

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

This will allow apps from any developer to be downloaded and executed on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

For users, just **Right Click** the application or file > Click **Open**.

For developers, this is not a signing problem, but a notarisation problem. You should notarise your application. Have a look at [Notarizing macOS Software Before Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Steps to fix this warning:

Click on Cancel on the message,

Now go to Apple Menu: System Preferences...

Click on Security & Privacy,

Go to Genrals Tab,

Here you should see "Allow apps downloaded from: "Android Emulator" was blocked from use. because it is not from an identified developer.

Click on the lock to Autenticate and make changes:

Click on open Anyways

You will again see a warning: Just click on Open button

Answer (score 1):

The "Anywhere" option is now gone in macOS Big Sur (Apple M1). So, to open an application with the error: "... cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified" you must perform following steps:

1. Open Finder
2. Tab Applications
3. Find your application
4. Right click -> Open

After that, the application (for me it was "x2goclien") opens not only in this way, but also from the Launchpad menu.