# SoapUI 5.7 & 5.6 MacOS Installer and multiple libprism warnings: "will damage your computer"

Tags: javafx, soapui, apple-m1, openjfx

Using Apple M1 13.4.1 I do got since today multiple warning that

```
"libprism_es2.dylib" will damage your computer. You should move it to the Trash.
```

whenever I run the SoapUI-5.7.0.app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563544/cant-be-opened-because-the-identity-of-the-developer-cannot-be-confirmed)

Comment: I have the same problem on an Intel Core i7. Started today 25/July/2023

Comment: @Siguza this problem and solution has a different cause from the issue you reference.  SoapUI-5.7.0 has dependencies on JavaFX 16, with which it ships.  But there is no JavaFX 16 version for M series Macs, so SoapUI can't function correctly on those systems.  The fix (until SoapUI updates their app) is to patch the JavaFX distribution used by SoapUI to a version which is compatible with M series Macs.  Note that users might *also* experience the issue in the linked answer, which they would still need to address *as well*.

Answer (score 14):

Based on @Splioo's excellent self-answer I created some sh for an easy fix:

```
ls -l /Applications/SoapUI-*.app/Contents/java/app/lib/javafx*
cd /Applications/SoapUI-*.app/Contents/java/app/lib
export v=19.0.2.1
for j in base controls graphics media swing web; do
  echo rm -v javafx-$j-*-mac*.jar
  echo curl -sS https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/$v/javafx-$j-$v-mac-aarch64.jar --remote-name
done
ls -l /Applications/SoapUI-*.app/Contents/java/app/lib/javafx*
```

This lists the old libs, (blindly, since a reinstall is trivial) removes the old libs, downloads the new ones based on the version you choose & list the new ones. After you have validated it does what it says by running, remove the `echo`s and run again.

Condensed oneliner for the TL;DR'ers:

```
( set -x; cd /Applications/SoapUI-*.app/Contents/java/app/lib/; v=19.0.2.1; for j in base controls graphics media swing web; do rm -v javafx-$j-*-mac*.jar; curl -sS https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/$v/javafx-$j-$v-mac-aarch64.jar --remote-name; done; ls -l /Applications/SoapUI-*.app/Contents/java/app/lib/javafx*; )
```

Comment: This works for me with version `19.0.2.1`, thank you!

Comment: lol, one line ftw :-)

Comment: BTW: As a rule of thumb for myself, if I create complex oneliners on the cmdline, I always build & run it with extra `echo`s in there so I can run it and inspect the `set -x` output. That way I can visually validate if it behaves as expected before actually executing the "dangerous stuff". Goes together nicely with `export PS4='\033[0;33m+\033[0m '`. Maybe this saves somebody's hide out there.

Answer (score 3):

Waiting for the SoapUI's team to release a new version with a valid certificate you can directly download binarries here `SoapUI-5.7.0-mac-bin.zip` : https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/releases/tag/v5.7.0

Afterwards you can simply run `~/Downloads/SoapUI-5.7.0/bin/soapui.sh` in a Terminal window to start SoapUI

Comment: thanks. note: It does not work on MacOs M1 and M2

Answer (score 2):

I've opened `SoapUI-5.7.0.app>Contents>java>app>lib` and renamed als `javafx-*` binaries to `_bak` and downloaded from here : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/
the respective 17.0.1 binaries and dragged them into above folder.

I did start soapui via commandline ./soapui.sh in
`/Applications/SoapUI-5.7.0.app/Contents/java/app/bin` directory

[image: SoapUI-5.7.0.app>Contents>java>app>lib]

Comment: This works because the JavaFX 17 mac-aarch64 jars contain native JavaFX code for the Apple M processors (unlike the 16-mac jars which contain native code for x64 processors).   This is a packaging and distribution issue with SoapUI, it should be shipping a version that supports Apple M processors which includes the correct jars for that platform.

Comment: Note, it may be a better idea to [use a more modern JavaFX version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75160212/1155209).

Comment: The weird thing is that it worked until I did some minor OS upgrades and from that moment on  it behaved as described.

Comment: I think SOAPUI is mainly a Swing app, I don't know how much it actually uses or requires JavaFX.  Obviously, since it has the jars, it uses JavaFX technology, including the web and media stacks, but it may not be part of the core SoapUI functionality.  I don't know what the link to the OS upgrade is though.

Comment: Would you elaborate on your solution please? I have the same problem on an Intel x86_64. I tried different versions of Amazom Corretto and downloading different versions of `openjfx`, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you use windows or mac os? Which version of soapui did you download?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your continued patience!

We are pleased to announce that we now have a new release 5.7.1 out.

## SoapUI Open Source 5.7.1

##### Released on 2023-08-01

Fixed an issue where SoapUI version 5.6.0 and 5.7.0 would not install or open on certain machines including Mac OS Ventura. There were issues with an expired Apple Certificate and previous bundled JRE environment.  We have signed the new version with updated Apple Certificate and also updated the bundled JRE environment to Liberica version 16.0.2+7. These updates which resolves this issue for Mac users and the application now installs properly. Windows and Linux versions also received updates to the bundled JRE environment.

Links are below.

- Github Release

  - https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/releases/tag/v5.7.1
- Official Download Page

  - https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release/
- Release Notes

  - https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release/release-notes/
  - https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/release-5.7.1/RELEASENOTES.txt

Thanks again for using SoapUI and bringing the issue to our attention.

Saf

---

Thanks for the report(s). The SmartBear team are actively looking into this and will update with timelines once we have more insights on a resolution.

If users could update their bug reports to state which macos version, and processor they are using, this would be helpful in ensuring we can test against all affected versions. The OP has done so in this SO post, thank you!

You may note, this is also raised as a GitHub Issue https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues/773

we will provide updates in both places.

Hope that helps as an interim.

Yousaf

---

Update:

Hey all,

Thanks for the patience on this matter.

The SmartBear team is making good progression resolving. The issue arises from the previous JRE environment used in SOAPUI which is not working with at least the latest version of Mac Ventura.

The team has updated JRE to Liberica JRE version. 16.0.2+7 and currently testing the application builds and installs correctly.

Once all QA is complete, we will release new installers and update on the community forums.

Please continue to update bug reports to state which MacOS versions and processors you are using so we can ensure we are test against all affected versions.

Thank you!

Tracking issues

- GitHub Issue https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues/773
- Stack Overflow [SoapUI 5.7 & 5.6 MacOS Installer and multiple libprism warnings: "will damage your computer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757666/soapui-5-7-5-6-macos-installer-and-multiple-libprism-warnings-will-damage-yo)

we will provide updates in both places and more updates to follow in due course!

Answer (score 0):

### If you have SoapUI installed:

Follow the steps outlined by [`@jubr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76764185/2035207) to update [`JavaFX`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/).

### If you don't have SoapUI installed:

The solution is inspired by [`@gokulgovind`](https://github.com/gokulgovind) on [`Github`](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues/772).

###### 1. Download [SoapUI v5.6.1 for macOS](https://dl.eviware.com/soapuios/5.6.1/SoapUI-5.6.1.dmg).

###### 2. Right-click on `SoapUI-5.6.1.dmg` and select `Open`

[image: SoapUI-5.6.1.dmg - Open]

###### 3. Right-click on `SoapUI 5.6.1 Installer.app` and select `Get Info`

[image: SoapUI 5.6.1 Installer.app - Get Info]

###### 4. Click to select `Override Malware Protection`, then press `Allow Anyway`, and enter your password when prompted.

[image: General - Override Malware Protection]
[image: Allow Anyway]

###### 5. The installer will complete and you can start `SoapUI v5.6.1`

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything like this

Comment: @f.trajkovski "_anything like this_". Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Which step? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I tried the steps that you proposed but when clicking on Get Info I wasn't able to find anything like Override Malware protection

Comment: @f.trajkovski make sure you `Get Info` on the `SoapUI 5.6.1 Installer.app` and NOT on the `SoapUI-5.6.1.dmg` file.